# How do I perform a logic comparison using dynamic T-SQL with an empty string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

When executing the sample code included below, with the variables I've included where name/pw are set to blank strings (''), the iif comparison operator is not returning null under any circumstance as far as I can tell. Am I correctly performing this check? I am new to dynamic SQL and am attempting to convert some utility scripts I wrote to get a better understanding. I haven't even begun trying to concatenate @SMTPPORT and @SMTPSSL instead of the 25/0 because the error doesn't make sense to on that line.

```
-- SMTP Settings if desired; leave blank if you wish to use defaults for troubleshooting
DECLARE @SMTPSERVER nvarchar(max) = 'localhost' -- SMTP Server, defaults to localhost
DECLARE @SMTPPort int = 25 -- SMTP Port, default 25
DECLARE @SMTPUID nvarchar(max) = '' -- SMTP Username
DECLARE @SMTPUPWD nvarchar(max) = '' -- SMTP Password
DECLARE @SMTPSSL int = 0 -- Enable TLS? 0 is default (no)
DECLARE @SMTPOverRide nvarchar(max) = '' -- E-mail sender override

DECLARE @SmtpCMD nvarchar(max) = N'
DELETE FROM TM_EmailConfiguration

INSERT INTO TM_EmailConfiguration (SMTPServer, SMTPUsername, SMTPPassword, SMTPPort, SMTPSSl, EmailSenderOverride, TMGUID, LMG, LMD, LMU)

VALUES (
    '''+ @SMTPSERVER + ''', 
    '+ (SELECT IIF ( @SMTPUID != '''', ''''+ @SMTPUID +'''', NULL)) + ', 
    '+ (SELECT IIF ( @SMTPUPWD != '''', ''''+@SMTPUPWD+'''', NULL))+ ', 
    25, 
    0, 
    ''Test@WK.com'', 
    (select * from V_TM_TMGUID), 
    (select * from V_TM_TMGUID), 
    getdate(), 
    ''Sean'')

'
EXECUTE SP_ExecuteSQL @SmtpCMD
```

Comment: Use PRINT @SmtpCMD to inspect your dynamic SQL, and make changes as appropriate.

Comment: Good day Sean, you said that "`the iif comparison operator is not returning null`", which is not correct. The issue is that `NULL` is not the same as `empty string`. Empty string `''` is a value, while NULL is no not a value. The solution for these cases is simply to compare `ISNULL(Column_Name, '')`, which mean that any NULL will be replaced by empty string

Comment: @RonenAriely I upvoted your comment, but later realized he has NULL as the return value of the IIF() for false -- Tab nailed this one I think.

Comment: Hi @JeffBreadner - I appreciate that! I was using SELECT to identify the code, but I was having trouble in identifying how to resolve the problematic code. I am about to attempt Tab's below test.  (Edit: I Didn't know enter would post this) -- Dave is correct in that NULL is the return value of the IIF() and is not being checked for in the comparison operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be doubling the single-quotes in the comparison check.

Also, as Grambo pointed out, if want NULL in your dynamic sql string, you need to concatenate the string value `'NULL'` instead of actually concatenating `NULL`.

Instead of this:

```
   '+ (SELECT IIF ( @SMTPUID != '''', ''''+ @SMTPUID +'''', NULL)) + ',
```

you should be doing this:

```
   '+ (SELECT IIF ( @SMTPUID != '', ''''+ @SMTPUID +'''', 'NULL')) + ',
```

Finally, I'm trusting that you have some self-education purpose for doing this with dynamic sql because there's nothing being done in your sample code that can't be done in regular (non-dynamic) sql.

Even more finally, in your final code if you need to use dynamic sql because you're using variables for databases, tables etc, you can still avoid doing this particular comparison outside of the dynamic context (sorta, since the variable does exist outside of it) by using the handy-dandy NULLIF() function like this:

```
NULLIF('''+@SMTPUID +''',''''),
```

(Note that the line above is INSIDE the dynamic sql statement.   The only thing that is outside of it is `+@SMTPUID +`

Comment: This still will not work for NULL since you compare `@SMTPUID` to empty string. You should use `ISNULL(@SMTPUID,'')` instead of `@SMTPUID`

Comment: actually I thikn you want the following where the NULL is inside of single quotes since concatenating to NULL will make the whole expression NULL.

 '+ (SELECT IIF ( \@SMTPUID != '', ''''+ \@SMTPUID +'''', 'NULL')) + ',

Comment: Actually @grambo25 is right.. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @RonenAriely read the question again more carefully.  You're reading it differently from me, and I'm pretty sure I'm reading it right.   OP is asking how to compare the value to an empty string.   The question is not asking how to compare the variable value `@SMTPUID` to NULL.   I grant you that adding `ISNULL` wouldn't hurt anything (other than a little performance overhead), but it's more than the OP is asking for.

Comment: True, he want to compare @SMTPUID to empty string, but When the variable @SMTPUID is NULL then the the condition `@SMTPUID = ''` is false since NULL is not like empty string. The OP mentioned that he never IIF does not compare NULL which is wrong. He tried to compare @SMTPUID to empty string and when @SMTPUID IS NULL that he got false. He should use `ISNULL(@SMTPUID,'')` for this, if he want to get the rows with null when he compare to empty string.... In any case, I see that the question was changed so I need to re-read the updated question if I want to understand what is different now...

Comment: @RonenAriely Well you'll see that in the sample code he explicitly sets `DECLARE @SMTPUID nvarchar(max) = ''`, and the question (as of this writing) is only about how to get the sample code to work, so we don't need to worry about `@SMTPUID` being NULL for purposes of this question, I'm thinking.

Comment: Thanks TabAlleman and Ronen Ariely, I wanted to compare SMTPUID to an Empty String and then IF the string is empty, enter a null value (hence the comparison, != '', @SMTPUID, Null (if NOT blank string, enter string, else null). The ISNULL comparison would be relevant here if I was declaring the value as null, but because I am approaching this from the idea of easily modified variables for reuse, I want to have a section that's clearly indicating where to enter a value which precludes me from declaring but not initializing the variable. I will be giving your initial answer a test momentarily.

Comment: @TabAlleman , It is very hard to have a discussion when the history is changed all the time, which `is one of the reasons I hate stackoverflow interface`. Since we have no option to add comments with formatted code and real content but only poor one line text, the procedure that the community decided in time is that the OP change the original post and this make the entire discussion irrelevant. "`and the question (as of this writing) is only about how to get the sample code to work...`"  well we can focus on the new updated question as you said :-)

Comment: Adding on to my previous comment (now that Tab's reply is visible), Tab is correct - I am not concerned about checking for a potential null value here. I am trying to establish automated troubleshooting methodology in dynamic SQL instead of regular T-SQL and part of that is encapsulating the actual checks and balances behind the scenes and only asking the user (person executing the script) to fill in variables. I do not feel comfortable leaving the variable uninitialized (`DECLARE @SMTPUID nvarchar(max) -- = 'Value here'`) although viable. Also, I didn't edit my original question.

Comment: @TabAlleman This solution worked and I really appreciate the notes. I realize now that I'm not escaping my comparison because I'm already operating outside of the escaped statement - which I was originally doing but had a totally different problem with. Yes, I am doing this because some variables I excluded from code specify database changes, etc.-- this was a snippet of sample to identify the problem I was having but the finished product is much longer and include sinput you need dynamic sql for (variable-wise). This project is for self-edification or I would've taken the easy way  out :)

Comment: Let's start from the start @SeanBrookins. (1) Please provide queries to create your original table (TM_EmailConfiguration) and to insert several rows. (2) Please provide the static queries that you want to execute in specific cases (set sample data to the variables and give us the static query that should be executed in each case). Next we will help you to make the dynamic query based in the static queries

Comment: Hi @RonenAriely so I'm creating a script that goes through roughly 11 tables across 3 databases based on variables at the top in order to automate setting a database into a default state, and then inputting setup values to essentially complete initial setup. The reason I'm using dynamic SQL is primarily to section off each function into its own command and be able to take database names as parameters, along with some light security checks/object checks. I will probably have more questions over time but I am doing this to learn d-sql overall, so I want to make sure I can do the work myself. :)

Comment: I am trying to point you to the right way to "make sure you can do the work yourself". Work with me step by step as this is how you should do it yourself. First provide what I asked for yourself (and for us in order to move to the next step). We need more code/samples and less stories at first step. lets see examples (I will probably go to sleep soon so maybe I will get it only tomorrow or next time I come to stackoverflow, but this is the way you should work - first static queries an then when all is clear and all options of the dynamic query was tested as static, we can bulb the dynamic...

Comment: Hi Ronen, I will provide a code sample to you once I can compile it all so that you can review and comment. The table structures are a little more difficult because some of the values are being auto-generated and I am only providing what is required/relevant when inserting, but it will take me some time to get all of this together in a readable format for you. Perhaps this would be a separate question? I don't want to edit my original post when it has been fully addressed by Tab.

Comment: Definitely a new question.  This wall-o-comments is big enough, thank you.  ; )

Comment: Hi @TabAlleman thank you for the note about NULLIF, I had never seen that expression before and it works perfectly - plus is much more concise!